# Align Input Text to begin from the Left like Placeholder text

Tags: react-native

This React Native App uses Galio Framework  { Input, Block } from 'galio-framework';
I set the value of text by passing the text captured in another component, a Webview.

```
const currentProduct = navigation.getParam('productN', '');
```

Here is the CSS

```
textInput: {
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    borderRadius: 5, //(Metrics.WIDTH * 0.42),
    marginTop: 10,
    paddingTop: 10, 
    paddingBottom: 10,
    paddingLeft: 15,
    paddingRight: 15,
    height:50,
    elevation:3,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    width: (Metrics.WIDTH * 0.74),
    fontSize: Fonts.moderateScale(16),
    fontFamily: Fonts.type.sfuiDisplayRegular,
  }
```

The Input:

```
<Input style={styles.textInput}
                            placeholder = "Product name(optional)"
                            //" Product name(optional)"
                            placeholderTextColor = "#b7b7b7"
                            underlineColorAndroid = "transparent"
                            autoCapitalize = "none"
            textAlign="left"
            keyboardType = "default"


          ref="productname" 
          onChangeText={(productname) => this.setState({productname })}
          value={currentProduct}

                         />
```

This is what it is currently displaying:

[image: picture]

I need it to display properly, example text:

```
BELLA 14745 Electric Tea Kettle, 1.5 LITER, Silver Tile
```

Comment: I  dont understand what do you want to achieve. if you want to just align text use textAlign style property right or left not as props  else if you want to make the whole text rtl then its another thing

Comment: I have edited the RTL out and also in the code. Still same issue. That was for internationalization. I want the text aligned normal starting from the beginning of the left just like the placeholder. That text was passed in from another component where the text was gotten from.

Comment: I think your css for height may be an issue since you have fixed it. Try creating min height and max height for it and bind it to your textarea.

Comment: The text is not appearing completely horizontally and not starting from the left. It obscures. Can you provide example. I have tried minHeight. And problem persist. I want the text captured to appear as default text.

Answer (score 0):

The key here is textAlignVertical property.

```
input: {
  flex: 1, 
padding: 4, 
marginRight: 1, 
marginTop: 5, 
fontSize: 18, 
borderWidth: 1, 
borderRadius: 4, 
borderColor: '#E6E5ED', 
backgroundColor: '#F8F8F9', 
justifyContent: 'flex-start', 
height: 150,
textAlignVertical: 'top'
}
```